# Implementing a following system and fetching posts of people a user follows in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I am designing a social media site and have a model of follower/following system that when a following relationship is made the feed will get all the posts by the followers of the user, I have tried to make the model for my user class and the post class as following:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    posted_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date= models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time=models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    media=models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

and this is the model that establishes the relationship between two users.

```py
class Following(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user_id= models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='followers',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user_id", "following_user_id")
```

But when I try to combine things while calling upon the posts of the concerned user through this code

```py
class Feed():
    def __init__(self,User):
        self.following=Following.objects.filter(user_id=User).values('following_user_id')

    def GetPosts(self):
        self.post=Post.objects.filter(posted_by__in=self.following)
```

But this returns me an empty list even after creating the objects, If any of you guys could help me with it in anyway, I would really appreciate it.

### Edit

The issue has been resolved, the queryset had to be parsed to obtain the User objects and fix the naming convention in model fields as suggested by @Melvyn

#### Models

```
class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user= models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='followers',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user_id", "following_user_id")
```

### Timeline

The file which gets the post of following users.

```
class Feed():
    def __init__(self,user):
        temp=Following.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.following =[temp[i].following_user for i in range(len(temp))]
    def GetPosts(self):
        self.post=Post.objects.filter(posted_by__in=self.following)
```

Comment: You should never name a foreign key "_id", it's a model relation and under the hood Django makes a field that ends in "_id" for the database, so now you have `user_id_id`. Relations between models are not "ids" but object relations. A user follows a user, not an id.

Comment: I have tried this edited the code as you have suggested, I really appreciate that you've rectified this mistake, however I'm still in search for a solution to my problem.

Comment: `self.following=Following.objects.filter(user_id=User).values_list('followers', flat=True)` will give a list of user ids. which you are trying to get using list comprehension

Comment: Also, I'm just curious. Why not a `ManyToMany` field in `User` model instead for the `Following` model ?

Comment: Yes, just tried that and it Works thanks for the input, it optimized the code.
The Thing with ```Many to Many``` relationship was that I was getting errors that I was getting posts of current user too, which I want to avoid. plus separating that into a different model made code more readable for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line of code `self.following=Following.objects.filter(user_id=User).values('following_user_id')` 
values('following_user_id') is returning a list or dict and not an object, but in GetPosts() you are filtering on object `self.post=Post.objects.filter(posted_by__in=self.following)`

self.following should be user object.

solution

remove
values('following_user_id') and make changes in change the GetPosts(self) to
self.post=Post.objects.filter(posted_by__in=self.following.user_id)

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to answer this, but unfortunately this doesn't work the code returns that ```Query set object has no attribute user_id```. Can serializers be used in this situation to parse the data?